# JavaScript loop for auto adding values based on previous value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, loops

I am getting values from PHP array and storing in JavaScript variable array.

```
var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $count_common_months_arr).'"' ?>]; 
/* Result for js_array is : 5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4 */
var table_data_array = [0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90,2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90,0.40,0.30,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,];
```

I want slice the array using loop for getting as given below by using jQuery or JavaScript loops.

```
table_data_array.slice(0, 5);   start_value = 0; end = 5(first value in js_array) 
/* Note: Taking End values from js_array variable */
table_data_array.slice(5, 9);   start = 5; end = 5+4(second value in js_array) = 9;
table_data_array.slice(9, 13);  start_value = 9; end_value = 9+4(third value in js_array) = 13;
table_data_array.slice(13, 18); start_value = 13; end_value = 13+5(fourth value in js_array) = 18;
table_data_array.slice(18, 22); start_value = 18; end_value = 18+4(fifth value in js_array) = 22;
table_data_array.slice(22, 26); start_value = 22; end_value = 22+4(sixth value in js_array) = 26;
table_data_array.slice(26, 31); start_value = 26; end_value = 26+5(seventh value in js_array) = 31;
and so on...

if we execute table_data_array.slice(0, 5) /* 0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90 */
if we execute table_data_array.slice(5, 9) /* 2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90 */
and so..on..
```

I used below loop and didn't find any logic to get the result as above.

```
for (i = 0; i <= js_array.length; i++) {
        var end = js_array[i];
        var start = 0;  
        console.log(table_data_array.slice(start, end));
    }
```

Please help me out..I am new to this programming

Comment: In example, sometime you are fetching 5 elements and sometimes you are fetching 4 elements. Is there any conditions for that ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I assume you want to do increment the start value based the current value in the array. So you just need to do `var end = start + js_array[i];` Define start outside of the loop and set the new start value after the "log".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the array that way and create a new one containing those slices you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` combined with `Array.prototype.splice` like this

```js
const js_array = [5,4,4,5,4];
const table_data_array = [0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90,2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90,0.40,
  0.30,0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90,2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90,0.40,0.30];


const result = js_array.reduce((acc, v) =>
  acc.concat([table_data_array.splice(0, v)]), []);

console.log(result);
```

And if you really want to use loop then you can do this.

```js
const js_array = [5,4,4,5,4];
const table_data_array = [0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90,2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90,0.40,
  0.30,0.10,0.15,0.10,0.10,0.90,2.50,0.10,0.90,0.90,0.40,0.30];

let counter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < js_array.length; i++) {
  let slice = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < js_array[i]; j++) {
    slice.push(table_data_array[counter++]);
  }
  console.log(slice);
  slice = [];
}
```